# Replace a string at particular position with another string without hardcoding in java

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am reading a string from file at a specific position and i need to make some conversions by calling a function and the resultant string has to be replaced in the same position. Below code throws me Illegal repetition error since my string contains characters such as '}','{'. I dont know how to escape these characters when it is specifically not hardcoded. Please help.

```
    String MFstr = strLine.substring(612,623);
    StringBuilder sbMFstr=new StringBuilder (strLine.substring(612,623));


    String temp="";
    if (mfn.isNegativeMFOrNegativeOverPunch(MFstr)){
        temp = "-"+MFstr;}
    else{
    temp=MFstr;}
    String number=mfn.MForOverPunchToNumber(MFstr);
    if( temp.startsWith("-")){
        //Positive is false
        number = "0" + number;

    }
    strLine.replaceAll(MFstr, number);  //This line throws Exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `replaceAll` is a regular expression. `{` and `}` are occurrence characters in regex. You could do

```
strLine = strLine.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(mfStr), number);
```

or simply

```
strLine = strLine.replace(mfStr, number);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Now it doesnt throw an exception, but value doesnt get replaced in the file. From the debugging console, i could see the values are coming correctly to that. For example, strLine.replace(00374400{,003744000) - This value comes up...But i dont see that it is getting replaced in the file. Is that something i am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you assigning the result back to the variable as shown above? remember Strings are immutable....

Comment: Yes i did that. In the debug console, i can see it is replaced..But not in the file. even though i can see file has been modified..NOt sure where i am going wrong. SHould i open writer function..

Comment: well....yes :) you need to use something like `PrintWriter` to write the data to disk.